# How to decide whether or not to set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property to true or false?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I am calling/starting .exe applications and .bat batch files from my C# windows forms application (I am also passing parameters). How do I determine whether I need to set the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property to true or false? What situations would true be better than false and vise versa?

I am using the ProcessStartInfo Class to set all the process information. I am then using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method to start the process based on my ProcessStartInfo.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = "[something]";
processInfo.Arguments = "[parameter1] [parameter2] [parameter3]";
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

I expect the processes to start and work properly. If I need to add more information/ clarify something please let me know, this is my first question.

Comment: It is explained in the doc : [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Castorix I still do not understand, what the difference is? Why should I choose to use shellexecute vs not use it

Comment: I added an answer with more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in .NET source :

- UseShellExecute  = true =>

internal function *StartWithShellExecuteEx* => calls [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw)

- UseShellExecute  = false =>

internal function *StartWithCreateProcess* => calls [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) or [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)

You usually use true when you want to launch the executable asociated with an extension.
like :

```
            using (Process p = new Process())
            {
                string sImage = @"e:\test.jpg";
                p.StartInfo.FileName = sImage;
                p.StartInfo.Verb = "open";
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.Start();
            }
```

If I set  false, it will fail because it will try to call CreateProcessW with "e:\test.jpg" as command line

Comment: thank  you this was more helpful in understanding the doc